# Grave danger or great danger

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

- You're in grave danger.
- You're in great danger.

Is 'great danger' correct? If then, what's the difference between 'grave danger' and 'great danger'?

Comment: Have you looked these words up and compared the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Great* = large, considerable.

*Grave* = serious.

Just two different ways of expressing the same idea.

Comment: +1, although to me "grave" sounds more intense than "great." This is somewhat subjective but in general I'd say great < grave < mortal.

Comment: Agreed with Type!A. **You're in great danger of losing your money to a scammer**.  **You're in grave danger of falling from a narrow path on a steep cliff.**